# Getting Qt to work in Fedora 12

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

Qt is installed by default in Fedora 12. Tried the hello world program:

```
 #include </usr/include/QtGui/QApplication>
 #include </usr/include/QtGui/QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
   hello.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

With normal compilation g++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.cpp, it shows:

> /tmp/ccfEv7zR.o: In function `main':
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined
>   reference to`
>   QApplication::QApplication(int&,
>   char**, int)'
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined
>   reference to
>   `QPushButton::QPushButton(QString
>   const&, QWidget*)'
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined
>   reference to`QApplication::exec()'
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined
>   reference to
>   `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined
>   reference to`
>   QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined
>   reference to
>   `QApplication::~QApplication()'
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined
>   reference to`
>   QApplication::~QApplication()'
>   /tmp/ccfEv7zR.o: In function
>   `QString::QString(char const*)':
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZN7QStringC1EPKc[QString::QString(char
>   const*)]+0x1d): undefined reference to`
>   QString::fromAscii_helper(char
>   const*, int)' /tmp/ccfEv7zR.o: In
>   function `QString::~QString()':
>   helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZN7QStringD1Ev[QString::~QString()]+0x2d):
>   undefined reference to`
>   QString::free(QString::Data*)'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   bash: ./helloWorld: No such file or
>   directory

and with

> qmake -project;qmake;make

it shows:

> /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/moc
>   /usr/include/QtGui/qapplication.h -o
>   /usr/include/QtGui/moc_qapplication.cpp
>   moc: Cannot create
>   /usr/include/QtGui/moc_qapplication.cpp
>   make: ***
>   [/usr/include/QtGui/moc_qapplication.cpp]
>   Error 1

Any idea how to get it to work?

**UPDATE:**
My cpp was already in a non-read-only directory. Now I changed the header to

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
```

and it shows this error:

> g++ -c -pipe -Wall -W -O2 -g -pipe
>   -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -DQT_NO_DEBUG  -I/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/mkspecs/default -I. -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include -o helloWorld.o helloWorld.cpp
>   helloWorld.cpp:1:25: error:
>   QApplication: No such file or
>   directory helloWorld.cpp:2:24: error:
>   QPushButton: No such file or directory
>   helloWorld.cpp: In function ‘int
>   main(int, char**)’: helloWorld.cpp:7:
>
>   error: ‘QApplication’ was not declared
>
>   in this scope helloWorld.cpp:7: error:
>
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘app’
>
>   helloWorld.cpp:8: error: ‘QPushButton’
>
>   was not declared in this scope
>
>   helloWorld.cpp:8: error: expected ‘;’
>
>   before ‘hello’ helloWorld.cpp:9:
>
>   error: ‘hello’ was not declared in
>
>   this scope helloWorld.cpp:10: error:
>
>   ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
>
>   helloWorld.cpp: At global scope:
>
>   helloWorld.cpp:5: warning: unused
>
>   parameter ‘argc’ helloWorld.cpp:5:
>
>   warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ make:
>
>   *** [helloWorld.o] Error 1

Comment: Show us your PATH and QDIR environment variables. Did you do a "custom" qt install or compiled your own at one stage?

Comment: @Derick: Are you the downvoter? I just received the "Popular Question" badge for this question. I didn't do a custom qt installed. In the very first line of my post I had mentioned that it was already installed by default in Fedora. First time I'm working with QT. How would I know about QDIR?

Comment: Nope wasn't me :) I suggest that you update your OS and Qt. If not try to search for the Fedora packages that have the Qt documentation and example code. There you'll see some samples with code that compiles with Qt3. (Is there a reason why your are on an "old" Fedora? Maybe install a new box? Tried a virtual machine such as VirtualBox or even [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)?)

Comment: Thanks. Am using Fedora 16 now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that /usr/include/QtGui/ is **"protected"**. (You do not have write permissions to that directory)

Move your helloworld.cpp to a directory that you have write access to. For example /home/*yourusername*/helloworld/helloworld.cpp

Change:

```
#include </usr/include/QtGui/QApplication>
#include </usr/include/QtGui/QPushButton>
```

To:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
```

Then try:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

I suggest you read a bit up on [using qmake](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-using.html). You will then understand why you had the first error: qmake helps you to get the includes and right libraries step by creating a Makefile for you.

**Edit:**

Another thing to check is to ensure qmake is in your path and optionally if the QTDIR environment variable is set.

Comment: Check your QTDIR variable and qmake in the path. Make sure they point to the same place. Also, make sure you do not have a mess-up in versions: Linux has a "native qt library" and you can install a custom one. If you installed a custom one ensure it's the FIRST in the path with QTDIR pointing to it.

Comment: @Nav : Show us your PATH and QDIR environment variables. Did you do a "custom" qt install or compiled your own?

Comment: **$PATH** shows "bash: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:.:/home/username/bin:.: No such file or directory" and **$QTDIR** shows "bash: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3: is a directory
".  I did not have to do an install of Qt. It came pre-installed with Fedora 12.

Comment: Well, something seems messed up :). If you can download and install "Qt SDK for Linux/X11 64-bit** (530 MB)" from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/. If you want to go ahead debugging see if your QApplication.h exsists and then change the headers to include the ".h". For example `#include "QApplication.h"`

Comment: Had already tried including qapplication.h. It exists. Program still does not work. Will try installing the downloaded version. Thanks :)

Comment: If you still want do debug ;) : Show me the error when you use `#include "QApplication.h"` Also, make sure it's not empty.

Comment: Hey, qapplication went thru. It's not a capital Q and A. when compiled with "qapplication.h", it didn't show any error. But with "qpushbutton.h", it shows the following error:

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘QPushButton::QPushButton(const char [13])’
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include/qpushbutton.h:141: note: candidates are: QPushButton::QPushButton(const QPushButton&)
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include/qpushbutton.h:70: note:                 QPushButton::QPushButton(const QIconSet&, const QString&, QWidget*, const char*)
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include/qpushbutton.h:68: note:                 QPushButton::QPushButton(const QString&, QWidget*, const char*)
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include/qpushbutton.h:67: note:                 QPushButton::QPushButton(QWidget*, const char*)

Comment: Ok, that is Qt3 specific (forgot sorry).. the header files are in lower case. For the 2nd error you MUST look at the doc at constructors. If you want to learn Qt look and compile the examples.

Comment: Actually I took the example from the internet: http://web.mit.edu/qt-dynamic/www/tutorials-tutorial-t1.html. But since one header is working, I guess I can get the others to work as well. What I'd really like is to get <QApplication> to work instead of having to specify the .h file. Thanks for your help Derick! At least now I won't have to download and install the SDK :)

Comment: If I recall correctly, that "feature" was only added in Qt4. They created special header files like QApplication that points to qapplication.h. In Qt3 you still need ".h" I suggest you go with Qt4 since most examples will be "up to date"

Answer (score 0):

From your compile log it's clear that you're using Qt 3.3.

This explains why you still can't get it to work.  The CamelCase-style headers, like QPushButton, were introduced in Qt 4.0.

Most likely you've used Qt 3.3 by accident.  Make sure that you run the qmake from Qt 4.  On many Linux distributions this is installed as `qmake-qt4`.

Comment: Firstly, I didn't install Qt. It came pre-installed with Fedora. Secondly, the camelCase headers are present in the Qt folder. The header contains just one line which is "#include<qapplication.h>". Anyway, I think a re-installation would be better.

Comment: I don't understand how whether or not you installed Qt or it was pre-installed is relevant to what I said.  What is "the Qt folder"?  Maybe you have Qt 3 and Qt 4 both installed (actually this is quite likely to be the case).